# Regex in vim for Makefile target

Tags: vim

I want to replace all the targets in a Makefile with something else using vim.  I'm sure this is possible with regex but I haven't figured out the syntax.

For example if I have

```
foo.o: $(src)/foo.c
```

I want to change this to:

```
SRC += $(src)/foo.c
```

I see that the vim search:

```
/\:
```

Gets me the colon.  But I'm not sure yet how to get the rest of the word (i.e. foo.o).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested. Typing the following command you will apply a global change which change text to colon, with `SRC +=` on lines matching the regexp `^[^[:space:]:]+`

```
:g/\v^[^[:space:]:]+/normal ^cf: SRC +=
```

`\v` is the switch for very magic mode (which you want to use most of the time). `^` means begining of line `^` inside square brackets means not any of this characters. In this case not spaces and not colon `+` means one or more times the previous character class. At the end the normal command does the substitution you want.

I recommend you to position the cursor on a line you want to change and try typing:
`^cf: SRC +=` to see if it's what you want to do

Comment: You should get rid of the spcae between `^cf:` and `SRC +=`. Otherwise I think it works.

Comment: it works, except as noted in the other comment the extra space needs to be removed.